# How can I handle runtime errors on Express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to express + node.js, so I'm written an rest api using mongoose. What's the best way to handle runtime errors as database errors etc.?

I've read in the express documentation that you can have a middleware `function(err, res, req, next)` to handle this errors, and you can call this function only calling `next(err)`. That's ok, so Imagine you have a `User` moongose model and in a controller you write this function:

```
const find = (email, password) => {
  User.find({ email: email }, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
      // handle error
    }
    return doc;
  });
};
```

Then, you have in another file a handler for a route:

```
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    userController.find(req.body.email);
});
```

So, at this point, you can handle the mongo error writing `throw(err)` in the model and using `try/catch` in the controller to then call `next(err)` right? But I've read that using `try/catch` in JavaScript is not a good practice because it creates a new execution context etc.

What's the best way to handle this errors in Express?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `try/catch` statements. Personally, I'd go for the approach of creating `Promises` for such actions so that I can use `.catch` for error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use promises. It not only makes your code cleaner but also error handling is much easier. For reference you can visit [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [this](https://www.promisejs.org/).

If you are using mongoose you can plugin your own library of promise.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(uri);

// plug in the promise library:
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`Mongoose connection error: ${err}`)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

And use it like below:

In controller:

```
const find = (email) => {
  var userQuery = User.find({ email: email });
  return userQuery.exec();
};
```

In Router:

```
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    userController.find(req.body.email).then(function(docs){
      // Send your response
    }).then(null, function(err){
      //Handle Error
    });
});
```